# TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'statistics')

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm having an issue passing my mongodb data via mongoose to my .ejs page.

```
app.get("/:dataset", function(req, res){

  Database.findOne({name: req.params.dataset}, function(err, dataBase) {

    const databaseName = req.params.dataset;

    if (!err) {

      if (!dataBase.statistics.topCities) {

        Database.aggregate([
          {"$unwind" : "$database"},
          {"$match" : {"database.data_name" : databaseName}},
          {"$sortByCount" : "$database.city"},
          {"$limit" : 3}
        ]).exec(function(err, cities){
          if (!err) {
            Database.updateOne(
              {name: databaseName}, {"statistics.topCities": cities}, function(err) {
                if (!err) {
                  console.log("Successfully added top cities");
                } else {
                  console.log(err);
                }
            });
          } else {
            console.log(err);
          }
        });

        Database.aggregate([
          {"$unwind" : "$database"},
          {"$match" : {"database.data_name" : databaseName}},
          {"$sortByCount" : "$database.state"},
          {"$limit" : 3}
        ]).exec(function(err, states) {
          if (!err) {
            Database.updateOne(
              {name: databaseName}, {"statistics.topStates": states}, function(err) {
                if (!err) {
                  console.log("Successfully added top states")
                } else {
                  console.log(err);
                }
              }
            );
          } else {
            console.log(err);
          }

        });

        res.redirect("/" + databaseName);

      } else {
        res.render("list", {
            data: dataBase,
        });
      }


    }
  });
});
```

As you can see here, I want to pass over a dataBase as data. This dataBase document looks something like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("630f1df25f58007e52b1ece9"),
    "name" : "walgreens",
    "database" : [
        {
            "data_name" : "walgreens",
            "city" : "Alabaster",
            "address" : "140 Market Center Drive",
            "state" : "AL",
            "zipcode" : NumberInt(35007),
            "full_address" : "140 Market Center Drive, Alabaster, AL 35007",
            "phone_number" : "205-663-4500 ",
            "_id" : ObjectId("630f16cfc95d5c58ff10f38d")
        },
        {
            "data_name" : "walgreens",
            "city" : "Alabaster",
            "address" : "9301 Highway 119",
            "state" : "AL",
            "zipcode" : NumberInt(35007),
            "full_address" : "9301 Highway 119, Alabaster, AL 35007",
            "phone_number" : "205-664-4584 ",
            "_id" : ObjectId("630f16cfc95d5c58ff10f38e")
        },
        {
            "data_name" : "walgreens",
            "city" : "Pelham",
            "address" : "3340 Pelham Pkwy",
            "state" : "AL",
            "zipcode" : NumberInt(35124),
            "full_address" : "3340 Pelham Pkwy, Pelham, AL 35124",
            "phone_number" : "205-664-8027 ",
            "_id" : ObjectId("630f16cfc95d5c58ff10f38f")
        }
    ],
    "__v" : NumberInt(0),
    "statistics" : {
        "topCities" : [
            {
                "_id" : "Chicago",
                "count" : NumberInt(132)
            },
            {
                "_id" : "Houston",
                "count" : NumberInt(111)
            },
            {
                "_id" : "New York",
                "count" : NumberInt(100)
            }
        ],
        "topStates" : [
            {
                "_id" : "FL",
                "count" : NumberInt(818)
            },
            {
                "_id" : "TX",
                "count" : NumberInt(704)
            },
            {
                "_id" : "CA",
                "count" : NumberInt(572)
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Whenever I visit the page /walgreens, mongoose should give me the above mentioned document and pass it to my .ejs page. The code on my .ejs page looks as follow:

```
<h1><%= data.statistics.topCities[0]._id %></h1>
<h1><%= data.statistics.topCities[0].count %></h1>
<h1><%= data.statistics.topCities[1]._id %></h1>
<h1><%= data.statistics.topCities[1].count %></h1>
<h1><%= data.statistics.topCities[2]._id %></h1>
<h1><%= data.statistics.topCities[2].count %></h1>
```

When I visit /walgreens or any other dataset page, it will load the first time I visit it, but it will also immediately throw me an error in the terminal saying:

```
node:events:505
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'statistics')
    at C:\Users\****\Desktop\test-database\app.js:47:21
    at C:\Users\****\Desktop\test-database\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:5128:18
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:78:11)
Emitted 'error' event on Function instance at:
    at C:\Users\****\Desktop\test-database\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:5130:15
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:78:11)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

This is strange because as I mentioned, the first time I load the page, it will actually show my the data, but immediately after the app will crash:

[As you can see, the data.statistics call works when I load it the first time.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftgWq.png)

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the **dataBase** has exact data or not.
and to avoid the error, you just have to change your code a bit.

Instead of using `dataBase.statistics.topCities`
use conditional chining as : `dataBase?.statistics?.topCities`

This will solve the issue.